# Alternative method of high power constant current drive for LEDs

Tags: led, constant-current, switching-regulator

[image]

The only high power, constant current method I am aware of involves using a MOS switch in conjunction with an inductor to alternately power and disconnect the LED, achieving an average current flow.

However, this approach has a drawback, as it may exhibit flickering at low brightness levels.

Is there a circuit topology for linear LED constant current that supports power ratings in the range of 25W to 300W?"

[image]

Comment: Why would it exhibit flickering and low light output levels? At what frequency flickering is an issue to you, human-visible or something that interferes with cameras? Linear at 25-300W range does not sound very efficient.

Comment: I think you need to be careful with the word `linear`. Many may read that and immediately think `not switcher`. (Well, I do anyway.) At these power levels, you will likely want a switcher for efficiency.

Comment: if vcc is regulated close to the sum of the LED's Vf at the current you want, then you can remove your inductor and resistor and just use PWM to limit the average current from a reasonable maximum with few losses. If you want to be able to drive it very dim you might need a smaller cap than would fully remove ripple at brighter levels, so it's a bit of a trade-off with size and frequency.

Answer (score 1):

> using a MOS switch in conjunction with an inductor to alternately power and disconnect the LED, achieving an average current flow.

The sketch in your question shows an inverse buck which is a quite popular and efficient LED driver approach. It can be highly efficient and cost-effective. And the controllers (or ICs with internal MOSFETs) are widely available.

> this approach has a drawback, as it may exhibit flickering at low brightness levels.

When properly designed, no. Driving with PWM directly (like shown below) can be an option but requires utmost care as it'll have to employ some sort of current limiting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUSM6u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One problem with the above approaches is the dissipation: If V+ is higher than total LED branch voltage (i.e. n x V<sub>F</sub> of the series-connected LEDs) then the instantaneous (and the average) dissipation of the resistors and the MOSFETs will be higher as the brightness increases.

> Is there a circuit topology for linear LED constant current that supports power ratings in the range of 25W to 300W?

So you are looking for stove or a hob, apparently. Joking aside, your best bet is a switching LED driver. Can be an inverse buck or a regular buck or something else, depending on your input voltage and total LED voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is there a better constant current driving method for LEDs? It needs to be dimmable. I've noticed that the engineers at our company are struggling with flickering at low brightness levels! Haha!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a circuit topology for linear LED constant current that supports power ratings in the range of 25W to 300W?"

Forget linear, it's going to waste way too much heat.

If your range is 25-300W, ie 10-90%, you can use one of the [Meanwell ELG](https://www.meanwell.fr/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/ELGC-300/ELGC-300-spec.pdf) constant current power supplies. Mains input, constant current output, and a DIM input that takes either a DC voltage or PWM (which is converted to DC internally). They have several other models but none dim to 0%, there's a minimum brightness, so watch out.

> However, this approach has a drawback, as it may exhibit flickering at low brightness levels.

Your schematic is an inverted buck, a common circuit for LED driving.

The scope shows it is enabled with a PWM signal at around 20kHz (50µs period).

When enabled, the driver chip will turn the FET ON until current in the sense resistor reaches the set point, then regulate current by switching the FET. So on the scope you get a long ON-time at first then fast switching.

I drew the inductor current on your scope shot...

[image]

When the FET is ON, inductor current goes up. When it is OFF, inductor current goes down.

There is a gotcha with the PWM control. When the PWM goes low, it disables the driver chip and turns off the FET. **However** if the FET was already off, that won't do anything. This means PWM controls brightness... but in steps.

[image]

Now suppose PWM (green) goes down as shown when the FET is off. It doesn't matter at which point of the off-time it goes down, the result will be the same: the FET is already off.

However, if PWM goes down during the ON-time of the FET, it will turn off and shorten the ON-time, thus controlling brightness. So your PWM does control brightness... but somewhat only in an integer number of switching periods, plus a chunk of the last one, but only if it goes down when the FET is ON.

[image]

Since switching frequency depends on LED voltage, supply voltage, etc, these "steps" move around a lot, and as a result brightness control gets unstable at low levels.

In addition, at very low brightness PWM will go down before the driver's current setpoint is reached, so PWM controls FET on-time directly. This gives fine control but there is no regulation at all, power supply and LED voltage are not compensated.

Basically, if you want it accurate to low levels, you need a chip that does **average current regulation**. This means it needs a sense resistor in series with the LEDs, that monitors LED current constantly, not just when the FET is ON. This is less favorable for the inverted buck topology, because the sense resistor needs to be on the positive supply.

Comment: Thank you, Bobflux. This has given me a deeper understanding of the circuit topology. I truly appreciate it! As I am interning at a photography lighting company, I discovered that the photography lights ranging from 25W to 45W exhibit flickering that can be captured by the camera when the PWM duty cycle is below 20%.

Comment: You're welcome! Well the reason for that flickering is probably what I mentioned. Unfortunately LED color changes a little bit with current (google "color shift"). https://www.digikey.fr/en/articles/led-color-shift-under-pwm-dimming / https://www.lrc.rpi.edu/programs/solidstate/pdf/dyble-spie2005.pdf / If that's acceptable, you can have zero flickering with a buck constant current source (which actually regulates current). If that's not acceptable you have to use a very high PWM frequency.

Comment: But even if you use PWM, LED temperature also introduces color shifts, and obviously it gets hotter at higher brightness! So even if they use PWM to remove color shifts (at the cost of extra flicker), I wonder if it actually does... Also with high frequency PWM the smoothing cap (and LED capacitance) kinda smoothes the current, so you end up in between the two, with variable current (more color shift) and flicker from the PWM.